# Авто инкремент в mysql, увеличивается даже когда поставил unique

Tags: mysql

Есть база в MySQL, при добавлении записей поставил `unique` по названию, всё нормально, дублей в базе нету, но при добавлении новой уникальной записи всё равно дублирующую запись (которая не отображается в таблице), увеличивает инкремент на отсутствующую запись, в таблице дубля нету, а значение инкремента увеличивается! Как будто в фоне он занимает место, но в таблице нету.

Сама таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE ppl51 (
                id int auto_increment primary key,
                name varchar(30)not null,
                surname varchar(10)not null,
                age varchar(10)not null,
                UNIQUE KEY(name,surname));
```

Comment: Скорее всего это нормальная ситуация, с которой вряд ли что-то можно сделать. Ведь формируется новая запись до того, как делается попытка записать её в таблицу. А для этого берётся новый `id` с помощью автоинкремента. Потом запись пытается записаться в таблицу, ей это не удаётся, а инкремент уже "потратился". По идее в этом нет ничего страшного, `id` вам же нужен не для последовательной нумерации, а для уникальности. С уникальностью всё нормально, не смотря на пропуски.

Comment: Понял! Благодарю!